# JQuery Cycle 2: how to show the index of the first slide correctly?

Tags: jquery-cycle, jquery-cycle2

I use JQuery Cycle 2 and need to show the index of a slide when it is displayed.

Here is the HTML:

```
 <div id="slideshow"  data-cycle-auto-height="container" data-cycle-slides="> div"  >
    <div>slide 1</div>
    <div>slide 2 </div>
    <div>slide 3 </div>
    <div>slide 4</div>
</div>
<div id="caption"></div>
```

Here is the Javascript:

```
$('#slideshow').cycle({
    delay: 0
});

$('#slideshow').on('cycle-before', function (e, optionHash, outgoingSlideEl, incomingSlideEl, forwardFlag) {
    var caption =  (optionHash.currSlide + 1) + ' of ' + optionHash.slideCount;
    $('#caption').html(caption);
});
```

Here is the fiddle demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/mddc/kKD9S/1/

The problem is that when at page load the first slide is displayed, but the event "cycle-before" is not fired and the first slide seems to be treated at the last one.

What I did is wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 'cycle-before' event only fires before a transition happens.  When you initialize a slideshow, there is no transition, so this even will never get called.

Also, since the 'cycle-before' event gets fired before the change of slide, `optionHash.currSlide` will always be the previous slide, and since it is 0-indexed, you will be 1 behind.

To fix these issues, change your `cycle-before` event to `cycle-update-view` event, which gets fired after the slide has been updated, and will also be called after the cycle is initialized:

```
$('#slideshow').on('cycle-update-view', function (e, optionHash, slideOptionsHash, currSlideEl) {
    var caption = 'Image ' + (optionHash.currSlide + 1) + ' of ' + optionHash.slideCount;
    $('#caption').html(caption);
});
```

Here is a fiddle of it working: http://jsfiddle.net/ZY4uR/2/

Comment: @Bryan Your answer includes some nice tips on using Cycle events. I've posted a simpler approach that uses Cycle's caption options in case it's useful.

Answer (score 1):

Cycle 2 includes the `caption` and `captionTemplate` options which allow you to add a caption -- including the slide count -- without having to bind to one of Cycle's events.

```
$('#slideshow').cycle({
    caption: '#caption',
    captionTemplate: '{{slideNum}} of {{slideCount}}'
});
```

Check out the [Cycle 2 API](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/api/) and [caption demo page](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/caption.php) for more detail.